# Javascript clearing stack between calls?

Tags: javascript

I have a weird issue with this code

```
Moonbeam.Input.KeyboardState = function Moonbeam_Input_KeyboardState() {
    this._keys = new Array(2);
    this._resetKeys(); 
    } 

    Moonbeam.Input.KeyboardState.prototype = {

    _resetKeys: function Moonbeam_Input_KeyboardState$_resetKeys() {
        this._keys.clear();
    },

    _SetKeys: function Moonbeam_Input_KeyboardState$_SetKeys(keysPressed) {
        this._resetKeys();
        this._keys = keysPressed;
    }
}
```

I call the _SetKeys function and pass in a value, on the line this._resetKeys(); KeysPressed contains the value, on the line this._keys = KeysPressed, after returning from the call to _resetKeys(), keysPressed contains no value.

this is not the behaviour I expect, but javascript is not my speciality.

Can anyone tell me is this something I am doing wrong?

Is this how javascript works - I dont see how you could do recursion if it is.

I have also tried adding the line var _keysPressed = keysPressed; before the call to this._resetkeys() in the _SetKeys function but that also loses its value.

How do I get my values to stay during a call to another function?

stu.

Comment: keysPressed must contain the value after the function returns. Are you sure this is not what is happening?

Comment: How are you calling it? Are you modifying the array afterwards? If you pass a variable containing an array, then modifying that variable afterwards (no matter where) will also change it at the `_keys` property.

Comment: Secondly, I don't think an array has a method called 'clear'. Besides that, why do you want to `clear` a new array just after declaring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an array (or object parameter) to a function, it is not copied, the function receives a reference to that array.  When you then do `this._keys = keysPressed;`, `_keys` contains that same reference. When you later do `this._keys.clear();`, you're modifying that array.

I suspect what's happening is that you're calling `_setKeys()` with the same array as the previous call. So when it calls `this._resetKeys()`, it clears that array.

You either need to create new arrays as you need them, perhaps by copying them when receiving them as parameters or returning them as values.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the code is a bit redundant. Here's a simplified version of code, with a working demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/qz7q6/

Comment: Resetting before setting is also redundant.